# django sort by time

Tags: python, django, sorting

I'm trying to sort 3 upcoming events by date and time.
I was able to sort the dates by using

```
def get_upcoming_events(self):
    today=date.today()
    return Event.objects.filter(Q(start__gte=today) | Q(end__lte=today)).order_by('-start')[:3]
```

How would I sort the events by time? I read something about using lastest() but wasn't sure if I would need to declare another field to store time.

Comment: Not related, but what does that `__gte=today` and `__lte=today` do?

Comment: What's wrong with the above code? `order_by('-start')` should work fine for ordering

Comment: You should also paste your Event model in the question, might give a better solution.

Comment: I made little change to the code so it would look clear. return `Event.objects.filter(start__gte=date.today()).order_by('start')[:3]` So right now, I'm trying to set up a multi filter,to make this code can also filter event by date and time. Is there anyway  I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can order by several columns.  See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

```
order_by(*fields)¶
```

By default, results returned by a QuerySet are ordered by the ordering tuple given by the ordering option in the model’s Meta. You can override this on a per-QuerySet basis by using the order_by method.

Example:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005).order_by('-pub_date', 'headline')
```

The result above will be ordered by pub_date descending, then by headline ascending. The negative sign in front of "-pub_date" indicates descending order. Ascending order is implied.